# AttributeError: module 'tkinter.ttk' has no attribute 'filedialog'

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from __future__ import print_function
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk,filedialog
from tkinter.ttk import *
from placeHolder import *
import pandas as pd


tree = ttk.Treeview(daily_report, column=(1,2,3), show='headings',height=14)`
tree.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor=CENTER)

sb=Scrollbar(daily_report,orient=VERTICAL,command=tree.yview)
sb.place(x=760,y=150,height=305)

def file_dialog():
   filename = ttk.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="\",    title="select a file", filetype=(("xlsx files", "*.xlsx"),*
("All Files", ".*")))
   label_file["text"] = filename
   label_file["text"] = filename

browse_BTN = Button(viewData, text="Browse a File", fg=purple, relief="flat", width=12, height=2, borderwidth=0,
font=20,command=file_dialog())
browse_BTN.place(x=300, y=0)
```

Comment: 1) You should spend some time here [Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). 2) You need to provide more information then the code block. For instance `tk` version, Python version. What it is you are trying to achieve. **Add answers as update to question**. 3) `filename = ...` section does not look to be correct. Is this how it was in code or is there a copy and paste error? 4) Since you directly imported `filedialog` I believe it should be `filedialog.askopenfilename(...)`.

Comment: I tried to add filedialog library but it does not work , inside the file_dialog function I tried ttk.filedialog.askopenfilename and filedialog.askopenfilename and also do not work!!

Comment: Fieldialog isn't part of ttk. That's exactly what the error suggests

Comment: Show(as update to your question) the code you used with `filedialog.askopenfilename()` and the exact error message returned.

Comment: You have imported `filedialog`, so just use it directly without the `ttk.` prefix.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).